# Why am I getting different answers when I convert a string to a float, vs just using the float value from the start

Tags: python, string, floating-point, exponent, typecasting-operator

I am trying to convert 2 strings to floats, then raise one to the power of the other. For some reason the output of float('x') ** float('y') vs x ** y are sometimes not the same

For example:

```
float('-5') ** float('-5') 
0.00032
```

vs

```
-5 ** -5
0.00032
```

this is working fine; however, some numbers do not.
For example:

```
float('-5.04') ** float('-5.04')
-0.00028596440705202706+3.612570580059258e-05j
```

vs:

```
-5.04 ** -5.04
-0.0002882372438117746
```

(this bottom one is the correct answer btw)

Any suggestions as to why this is happening?

Comment: The bottom one is *not* the correct answer.

Comment: Try `(-5.04) ** (-5.04)`. Or `(-5.04) ** -5.04`. `**` has higher precedence than the unary `-`.

Answer (score 4):

`-5.04 ** -5.04` is evaluated as `-(5.04 ** -5.04)` because `**` has higher operator precedence than the unary `-`. You can see that by comparing the results:

```
>>> 5.04 ** -5.04
0.0002882372438117746
>>> -5.04 ** -5.04
-0.0002882372438117746
>>> -(5.04 ** -5.04)
-0.0002882372438117746
```

To "fix" this you would need to add parenthesis around the first number with its unary `-`:

```
>>> (-5.04) ** -5.04
(-0.0002859644070520271+3.6125705800592075e-05j)
```